# Ошибка Failure/Error: get :show, {id: question.id} в тесте rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Здравствуйте, есть такой тест:

```
it "renders show template if an item is found" do
  question = Question.create
  get :show, {id: question.id}
  expect(response).to render_template(assigns(:question))
end
```

За создание вопроса отвечает фабрика

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    title "test title"
    description "Test description"
    visitors 5
    association(:user)
  end
end
```

В модели две строчки валидации:

```
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
```

Метод show просто выводит вопрос. Объясните пожалуйста почему возникает ошибка:

```
  1) QuestionsController Show action renders show template if an item is found
     Failure/Error: get :show, {id: question.id}

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :id=>nil}
```

На сайте добавление вопроса работает.

Comment: ну видимо question не создаётся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку исправил так

```
it "renders show template if an item is found" do
  user = User.create
  question = FactoryGirl.create(:question, user_id: user.id)
  get :show, {id: question.id}
  response.should render_template('show')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не задали в фабрике идентификатор `id`, поэтому он принимает значение `nil`, и роутер неправильно формируется. Попробуйте добавить его в фабрику

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    sequence(:id)
    title "test title"
    description "Test description"
    visitors 5
    association(:user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Не помогло( Та же ошибка